# Limit number of characters in a line notepad++

Tags: notepad++, newline

For my git commits I use notepad++ and I would like to limit the number of characters in a line to 72 characters.
Normally, notepad++ show a sentence in a line until \n character, but I would like to automatically enter the content to the next line if the number of words exceeds a threshold. The Line mode just shows the vertical edge without entering to the new line.
[image]
Could you suggest me how to do it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you looking for `word wrap` ?
if it is the case then the steps are as follows :

1. Select “View” from menu bar.
2. From the dropdown menu click on “Word wrap” option.
3. The same steps are used to switch between Word wrap On & Off.

Comment: That word wrap only controls how the text is shown on the screen, it does not limit the length of lines. You can easily see this by altering the width of the Notepad++ window.